# Python Tool Windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, taskbar

```
TL.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
```

I'm making a GUI in Tkinter that uses a tool window, is there anyway to make this window show up in the task bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most systems, you can temporarily remove the window from the screen by iconifying it. In Tk, whether or not a window is iconified is referred to as the window's state. The possible states for a window include "normal" and "iconic" (for an iconified window). There are some others too.

```
thestate = window.state()
window.state('normal')
window.iconify()
window.deiconify()
```

Docs at : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm should be of some help.